# Hash table and the last value of a key

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I have a class of hash table. method 'add' adds key and a value. And when I add another value for the same key I would like to replace an old value on a new one. But I don't know what I have to change:)

```
class HashNode:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.next = None
        self.key = key
        self.value = value


class HashTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = [None] * 1000

    def hash(self, key):
        hashed = 0
        for i in range(len(key)):
            hashed = (256 * hashed + ord(key[i])) % 1000
        return hashed

    def add(self, key, value):
        bucket = self.hash(key)
        if self.table[bucket]:
            temp = self.table[bucket]
            while temp.next:
                temp = temp.next
            temp.next = HashNode(key, value)
        else:
            self.table[bucket] = HashNode(key, value)

    def find(self, key):
        bucket = self.hash(key)
        if not self.table[bucket]:
            return 'none'
        else:
            temp = self.table[bucket]
            while temp:
                if temp.key == key:
                    return temp.value
                temp = temp.next
            return 'none'

            

table = HashTable()
table.add('a', 1)
table.add('a', 2)
```

I am a getting key value '1' but I want '2'

```
table.find('a')
```

Comment: Instead of appending a new hash node at the end of a bucket you need to replace the first one with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @mkrieger1's comment: your question is the exact reason why the buckets are not simple cells and why you store the keys in the buckets. If you had no collision, that is `key1 != key2` implies `hash(key1) != hash(key2)`<sup>1</sup>, you wouln't need to store keys:

```
def add(self, key, value):
    bucket = self.hash(key)
    self.table[bucket] = value

def find(self, key, value):
    bucket = self.hash(key)
    return self.table[bucket]
```

But you might have collisions. That's why you are using a linked list to store several `(key, value)` pairs for the keys having the same hash. You correctly handled the collisions in the `find` method:

```
temp = self.table[bucket]
while temp:
    if temp.key == key:      # key found!
        return temp.value    # return the value
    temp = temp.next
return 'none' # why not None?
```

You should do the same in the `add` method:

```
temp = self.table[bucket]
while temp.next:
    if temp.key == key:     # key found!
        temp.value = value  # update the value
        return              # and return
    temp = temp.next
temp.next = HashNode(key, value) # key not found: create the entry
```

Both methods are now symmetrical.

<sup>1</sup>In maths terms, `hash` is injective. That is theoritecally possible assuming some conditions that are rarely met.

---

Remark: you could take advantage of a method that finds `HashNode`s:

```
def _find(self, bucket, key):
    temp = self.table[bucket]
    while temp:
        if temp.key == key:
            return temp
        temp = temp.next
    return None
```

And insert the new keys at the beginning:

```
def add(self, key, value):
    bucket = self.hash(key)
    node = self._find(bucket, key)
    if node is None:
        self.table[bucket] = HashNode(key, value, self.table[bucket]) # last parameter is next
    else:
        node.value = value

def find(self, key):
    bucket = self.hash(key)
    node = self._find(bucket, key)
    if node is None:
        return None
    else:
        return node.value
```

The symmetry is even more visible.